# Jest test failing for Mongoose query - Unable to figure out whats the problem

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, jestjs

I have the following test, its failing of the function getQuestionsByOrder(order) for "newest" order. I am sorting the ask_date_time in descending order and returning the res. But, I am not sure but the test is failing for some reason.

```
 test("get newest questions", async () => {
const questions = [
  {
    _id: "65e9b716ff0e892116b2de01",
    ask_date_time: new Date("2023-11-20T09:24:00"),
  },
  {
    _id: "65e9b716ff0e892116b2de04",
    ask_date_time: new Date("2023-11-21T09:24:00"),
  },
  {
    _id: "65e9b716ff0e892116b2de05",
    ask_date_time: new Date("2023-11-19T10:24:00"),
  },
];

mockingoose(Question).toReturn(questions, "find");

const result = await getQuestionsByOrder("newest");

expect(result.length).toEqual(3);
expect(result[0]._id.toString()).toEqual("65e9b716ff0e892116b2de04");
expect(result[1]._id.toString()).toEqual("65e9b716ff0e892116b2de01");
expect(result[2]._id.toString()).toEqual("65e9b716ff0e892116b2de05");
});
```

The error:

```
  ● question util module › get newest questions

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    Expected: "65e9b716ff0e892116b2de04"
    Received: "65e9b716ff0e892116b2de01"

      224 |
      225 |     expect(result.length).toEqual(3);
    > 226 |     expect(result[0]._id.toString()).toEqual("65e9b716ff0e892116b2de04");
          |                                      ^
      227 |     expect(result[1]._id.toString()).toEqual("65e9b716ff0e892116b2de01");
      228 |     expect(result[2]._id.toString()).toEqual("65e9b716ff0e892116b2de05");
      229 |   });

      at Object.toEqual (tests/question.test.js:226:38)
```

The function

```
  const getQuestionsByOrder = async (order) => {
  let query;
  switch (order) {
    case "newest":
      query = Question.find({}).sort({ ask_date_time: -1 });
      break;
    case "unanswered":
      query = Question.find({ answers: { $size: 0 } }).sort({
        ask_date_time: -1,
      });
      break;
    case "active":
      query = Question.find({})
        .populate({
          path: "answers",
          options: { sort: { answer_date: -1 } },
        })
        .sort({ "answers.answer_date": -1 });
      break;
       }
      const res = await query.exec();
       return res;
     };
```

Comment: It does not seem to have the chaining working correctly. You can mokc the sort too. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54561550/jest-mocking-spying-on-mongoose-chained-find-sort-limit-skip-methods